# Why does my customization manager screen not show items

Tags: acumatica

I'm in the process of upgrading from a 5.xx to a 2019 R2 version.  After importation into the 2019 R2 My customization project editor screen ends up blank, as follows:

[image]

If I go to File > Edit Project Items, it shows all the items.  The main problem here is that I can't update the dll and pdb files without that option on the left-hand pane.

Does anyone know how to get the items to show up on the main screen?

Comment: It is an AJAX glitch, how easy is it to reproduce? Does it do that in all browsers? Is it specific to a single customization project?

Comment: By the way, do you migrate straight from 5.xx to 19r2? I don't think it is supported. I think you need migrate to 17r2 first, or even to latest 6 first and to 18r2 after that. And only then it is safe to go to 19r2

Comment: It only gives me that problem for one (out of 5) customizations.  I can edit the items in the edit items window - but I just can't get the dll updated.  If I could find the FileID of the dll and pdb, I could do it manually in the window - but I don't know how to find that

Comment: If it's related to a specific customization I would advise to open the customization zip file (or File->Edit Project XML) and delete the various xml sections one by one until the issue disappear. Perhaps the project editor is parsing something unexpected which breaks the tree view population.

Comment: You can also open the browser console with F12 hotkey and check if there are any unexpected JavaScript errors.

Comment: Thanks, all - it was a SQL Script from the old 5.3 version that wasn't readable by the new 2019 R2 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by SQL Scripts that were generated by a very old version (5.3) and were not readable by 2019 R2.